# Put something between computer and printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

First of all, hi, my first question. 
I have a printer in my office and I want to make something that takes everything that is sent to the printer (it's wifi connected) and it copies it to my computer, I know it has to be always turned on but that's not a problem.

Thanks in advance for the answers, sorry if there is typos not too goo at english!

Comment: This would be easier if you could take the printer of of wifi, and connect it by USB to your computer instead. Then you can use your computer as a print server. Otherwise, you have to monitor all wifi traffic, looking for communications to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the MiTM (Man in the Middle) Attack on your Network, that's cool. 
Well i'm not expert in this area but i would suggest you to create something like a Server, connect your printer to this server via USB, and open Wifi Printer Sharing through your Server. With some more software (i guess) you will be able to monitor Printer's Queue and save all the files are being pushed to your printer.